# Creating a Custom Ubuntu Daemon

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, daemon

What's the "correct" way to create a custom daemon in Ubuntu, that will start at boot time and be controllable by Ubuntu's standard daemon start/stop commands?

Can I just copy and paste one of the scripts in /etc/init.d or do I need to "register" the daemon somewhere else?

Comment: Are you asking how to write a daemon or just launch one?  If the latter, you should clarify that then ask your question on superuser.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Done](http://embraceubuntu.com/2005/09/07/adding-a-startup-script-to-be-run-at-bootup/).

2nd result for Google: `ubuntu daemon startup`

Comment: Thanks. My search terms "creating an ubuntu daemon" found a lot of similar questions, but no answers quite so concise.

Comment: The preferred way is to use upstart. See the answer below for the link.

Answer (score 11):

Since you asked about Ubuntu specifically, you should know that sysv-style init scripts (the ones that live under /etc/init.d) are being phased out in favor of Upstart jobs, which IMHO are a lot easier to create and work with.  Here are some links to get you started:

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart

http://www.netsplit.com/category/tech/upstart/

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/init.5.html